# Very Slow query with replace function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question to my mysql query which is very very slow.

```
SELECT s0_.sku                                                                                           AS sku_2,
       (SELECT count(s1_.id) AS sclr_45
        FROM store_product s1_
        WHERE s1_.sku IS NOT NULL AND s1_.sku <> '' AND s1_.store_id = s0_.store_id AND s1_.sku = s0_.sku
           OR s1_.sku = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s1_.sku, '-', ''), '.', ''), '/', ''), ' ', '')) AS sclr_44
FROM store_product s0_
WHERE s0_.store_id = 5
GROUP BY s0_.id
HAVING sclr_44 > 5
ORDER BY s0_.sku ASC
```

esspesially this part `OR s1_.sku = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s1_.sku, '-', ''), '.', ''), '/', ''), ' ', '')) AS sclr_44`

If I remove it, the query is fast. I need to use replace function because i want to show all duplicate sku like 111 and 11.1 they are same because replace function removes dot.

How Can I increase performance ?  Now on the local database, query has execute over one minute.. if I removed replace, time is less than 1 secund.

There are a many more columns in main select

edit;

my explain plan

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: tag with database platform, run an explain plan, show indexes, etc.

Comment: What's the purpose of that REPLACE REPLACE etc?

Comment: Can you please share the execution plan. Also you are missing and and Or conditions.

Comment: replace allow me fetch sku which have speciall character and count it.

Comment: Please provide from your MySQL instance in TEXT format results of  A) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SELECT ( complete rest of your query ); B) SHOW CREATE TABLE store_product; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "store_product";  for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compare the "replaced" field with the s0_.sku instead of against itself (s1_.sku).

- Compared it with the s0_.sku

```sql
SELECT s0_.sku AS sku_2
  (
     SELECT 
       count(s1_.id) AS sclr_45
     FROM 
       store_product s1_
     WHERE 
       s1_.sku IS NOT NULL AND 
       s1_.sku <> '' AND 
       s1_.store_id = s0_.store_id AND 
       ( 
          s1_.sku = s0_.sku OR 
          s0_.sku = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s1_.sku, '-', ''), '.', ''), '/', ''), ' ', '')
       )
  ) AS sclr_44

  FROM store_product s0_
  WHERE s0_.store_id = 5
  GROUP BY s0_.id
  HAVING sclr_44 > 5
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

- `OR` is costly
- Sanitize the data *before* inserting.  This gives indexing a chance to be effective.  (And it obviates the need for `REPLACE` in the `SELECT`.)
- Pick one, not both:  `NULL` and `''` (unless they have some distinct meaning to your app).
- Probably `COUNT(*)` is better than `count(s1_.id)`
- Add these composite indexes:

  ```
    INDEX(store_id, SKU)
    INDEX(store_id, id, SKU)
  ```